# cURL error 58 error reading PKCS12 file in pem file

Tags: php, laravel, curl, pkcs#12, apple-developer

[i have pem.key file and .cer file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT58A.png)

GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 58: error reading PKCS12 file '/home/azureuser/nightshades/storage/app/public/documents/merchant_id.cer' (see
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://apple-pay-gateway.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession in file /home/azureuser/nightshades/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php file how to solve this